# Converting CSV to sqlite3 table in pandas - "8-bit bytestrings" error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sqlite

I am trying to load a table into sqlite3. I have it currently in a csv format. 
The table has multiple formats - text, number, date, NaN...

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
df.to_sql('file', conn, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

I get the following error:

ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings

Neither the database nor the sqlite table exist to begin with. I want to convert a csv to the file.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by adding an encoding to the read_csv part.

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", encoding='latin-1')
```